# How to unplug a portable hard disk from Windows 8 without shutting the computer down or damaging the disk?

Tags: windows-8

Does anybody knows how to unplug a portable hard disk from Windows 8 without shutting the computer down or damaging the portable disk? Is there any software to eject it beside windows safely remove that never works for me?

Comment: In what way doesn't eject work for you?  What happens when you use it?

Comment: almost always it says the disk is busy

Comment: In that case, eject is working properly.  The issue may be some other software that is failing to stop claiming that it's using the drive.  You need to figure out what that is and end that process.  BTW, if you shut down the computer gracefully, all processes will be properly terminated and the drive will be cleanly released, so that's always a fallback.  Remove the drive after the computer is shut down.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Safely Remove will only fail if your disk is in use.

I think that you need to find out why this is so.

You may use
[Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)
with the binoculars icon to search for all processes opening files on `X:`,
where X is your external disk.
This way you can pinpoint the process that is using the disk and maybe do
something about it.

There is no other way for you to safely remove a disk that is in use.

Comment: I ve used process explorer before but is useless cause it show me all disk information including internat hard disk and i cannot tell whats is the process that is using my jportable hd only

Comment: Use the binoculars icon.